# Unknown repetition of SeekBar.onProgressChanged()

Tags: java, android, seekbar

The onProgressChanged() method in seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener() is repeating itself number of times if i set the min value of seekbarprogress via seek.setProgress(1) and define the condition in onProgressChanged() via if statement please have a look at code below and log.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SeekBar seek;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    seek=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.myseek);
    seek.setMax(20);
    seek.setProgress(1);
    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            int min=1;
            if(progress<min){
                seek.setProgress(min);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(progress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("test",Integer.toString(progress));
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });

}
}




   05-25 11:00:41.834 1520-1520/com.example.dyno.seekbartimer I/test: 0
   05-25 11:00:41.846 1520-1520/com.example.dyno.seekbartimer I/test: 1
   05-25 11:00:41.849 1520-1520/com.example.dyno.seekbartimer I/test: 0
   05-25 11:00:41.861 1520-1520/com.example.dyno.seekbartimer I/test: 1
   05-25 11:00:41.864 1520-1520/com.example.dyno.seekbartimer I/test: 0
   05-25 11:00:41.867 1520-1520/com.example.dyno.seekbartimer I/test: 1
   05-25 11:00:41.870 1520-1520/com.example.dyno.seekbartimer I/test: 0
```

As you may see when i pull pointer to minimum position i,e is 1 the 0,1 repeating itself number of times..it will horrendous if put some method there and it start repeating itself...thanks

Comment: @pskink Nop please suggest some way to stop this repition

Comment: did you see `"boolean fromUser"` parameter? did you read the official documentation and what it is used for?

Comment: @pskink same issue..i used it below seek.setProgress(min); but nothing helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `seek.setProgress(min);` will trigger `OnSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged`

**To prevent this avoid changing the seekBar's progress in `progressChanged`. If its mandatory to do it, then use following approach:**

```
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            int min=1;
            if(progress<min){
                seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null);
                seek.setProgress(min);
                seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
                return;

            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(progress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("test",Integer.toString(progress));
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: @rachit3dev is it happening automatically or when you are trying to touch the Seekbar in UI?

Comment: your code help me a lot ,but i was getting same issue after applying suggested edits..one thing i put extra is "return" key after seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); and now this gives me exactly what i want..Thanks to u i just edited the answer so it can help others.

Comment: @rachit3dev not sure why your edit was rejected. I have updated my answer

Comment: dont you think that the last parameter passed to `onProgressChanged` method is used in cases like this one? why to make such workarounds with double calling `setOnSeekBarChangeListener` method?

Comment: @pskink we can use that but then the complexity of code would increase. In any case `onProgressChanged` will be called due to  `seek.setProgress`

Comment: `if(progress<min)` -> `if(!fromUser && progress<min)` what complexity you mean?

Comment: @pskink `if(progress<min && !fromUser)` won't be enough. It will still trigger `onProgressChanged` -> satisfy the condition and `seek.setProgress` will be called which will continue the cycle, we need to perform more checking.

Comment: @rachit3dev great! Remember to approve the answer if it was useful. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the listener when you set the progress and enable it once you set it.

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null);
        int min=1;
        if(progress<min){
            seek.setProgress(min);
        }
        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(progress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("test",Integer.toString(progress));
    }
```